# Choosing values of variables to generate perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am working on a Geometry problem and have translated it into a Number Theory problem but now I am stuck.

I have an expression of the form:

$$aM^2+bMN+N^2$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive integer constants that I know the value of.

I am trying to find positive integer values of $M$ and $N$ so the given expression is a perfect square.  I know that I can randomly pick values for $M$ and $N$ and hope I get a perfect square but that seems a bit crude.

I was able to complete the square on the given expression and got something of the form:

$$(pM+N)^2 - MN$$

where $p$ is a positive integer but I can’t see how that helps me.

Can anyone suggest an approach to finding values of $M$ and $N$ that will generate perfect squares?

Comment: Provide the values of $a $ and $b$.

Comment: @manlet_hunter a=4, b=3

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks!  I will look at that.